# Automapper map array of objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map an array of `object`s containing source classes, which has to be mapped to an array of `object`s containing destination classes. But It does work out of the box for my code.

```
class Class1ChildClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Class1
{
    // This array contains classes of type Class1ChildClass
    public object[] ClassesAsObjects { get; set; }
}

class Class2ChildClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    // This array should contain classes of type Class2ChildClass
    public object[] ClassesAsObjects { get; set; }
}
```

The straight-forward way in mind mind would be this code:

```
var cl1 = new Class1
{
    ClassesAsObjects = 
        new object[] {
            new Class1ChildClass
            {
                Value = 999
            }
        }
};

var config = 
    new MapperConfiguration(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Class1ChildClass, Class2ChildClass>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
        }
    );
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var cl2 = mapper.Map<Class2>(cl1);
```

Whatever I do, I always get an array of `Class1ChildClass` in the destination class `Class2`.

I tried to use `ForMember` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you want to use Automapper in this case instead of just manually doing the mapping. From my understanding, Automapper looks at the types and their properties, and does its magic with those.

However in your case, there is not much to leverage Automapper. You are using `object` which has no `Value` property. You want to map members of `object[]` but actually want the content to be somehow converted from one (object sub-)class to another.

But if you want to use Automapper, you can use the `AfterMap` to map the `ClassesAsObjects` member:

```
var config = 
    new MapperConfiguration(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
                .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                {
                    dest.ClassesAsObjects = src.ClassesAsObjects
                        .Select(x => 
                        {
                            return (x is Class1ChildClass)
                                ? (object)(new Class2ChildClass { Value = (x as Class1ChildClass).Value }) 
                                : null;
                        }).ToArray();

                });
        }
    );
```

Comment: This is just sample code to demonstrate my intention. The real data structures are much more complicated. The real two sets of classes are generated from 2 versions of XML schemas and I need to convert data from version 1 to version 2 with some modifications. Automapper has worked nicely for this, until I ran into the described problem. In your code you manually assign property Value from one object to another, which what AutoMapper is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

According to this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

> AutoMapper still requires explicit configuration for child mappings, as AutoMapper cannot "guess" which specific child destination mapping to use.

So you may need to add something like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(c=> {
    c.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
         .Include<Class1ChildClass, Class2ChildClass>();
    c.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try to use Include method, but it didn't work for me either. As I understood Include is for inheritance. But in my case Class1ChildClass does not inherit from Class1. It is just contained in it. So your code does not compile.

Comment: Yeah I answered too soon.  When I started fiddling with it I saw that it didn't.  My bad.  I'm currently looking at the problem.  It appears mapping from object[] of differing types to another object of different mapped types is not as straight forward than I was thinking it was.